# Como declarar uma fila de modo global?

Tags: c++

Quero que uma fila seja declarada de modo global. Declarei a fila da seguinte maneira no meu arquivo .h:

`extern std::queue<SotpPacket*> reg;`

Quero acessar a fila no meu arquivo .cpp, porém não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Então coloque seu código pra gente ver o que está errado.

Comment: Estou fazendo essa declaração, porém quando um no faz uma inserção na fila e em seguida outro no faz uma inserção e verifica os valores contidos na fila, não consegue enxergar o valor que o primeiro no inseriu. Como se o valor antigo tivesse se perdido

Comment: Quando um no 1 adiciona na fila, por exemplo, quando o no 2 for operar na fila eu quero que o que foi adicionado por 1 seja visível ao dois. So que isso não ta acontecendo. Parece que a info ta se perdendo

Comment: @RenandaSilvaAlves Acho que você está confundindo `extern` com uma espécie de "export".

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o problema esta no uso do `exter` no arquivo .h, ele indica a maneira com a qual o compilador vai armazenar a variável.

Sua variável de definição no arquivo header não deve conter a palavra `extern` a menos que esteja importando a variável de outro código fonte.

Sugiro que você faça a declaração de forma normal `std::queue<SotpPacket*> reg;` e utilize o `extern` nos códigos fonte que utilizam a variável.